# receiving repetitive result for conditional push array

Tags: arrays, conditional-statements, grouping

I'm trying to turn my array of object into new array of object based on their common object key and summing all the other properties of each objects. But I dont know why I keep receiving an array with correct item number but repetitive items (with the last new object). here is the code:

```js
function(){
    const list = [
        {
            amount: 0,
            date: '2018-11-29',
            source: 'a'
        }
        {
            amount: 2,
            date: '2018-11-29',
            source: 'b'
        }
        {
            amount: 3,
            date: '2018-11-30',
            source: 'b'
        }
    ]
    const daysGroup = []

    let dayGroup = {
            date: list[0].date,
            a: '',
            b: ''
        }

    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        

        if(dayGroup.date === list[i].date){
            switch (list[i].source) {
                case 'a':
                    dayGroup.a += Number(list[i].amount)
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    dayGroup.b += Number(list[i].amount)
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            console.log(dayGroup) 

        } else{
            console.log(dayGroup)
            daysGroup.unshift(dayGroup)

            dayGroup.date = list[i].date
            switch (list[i].source) {
                case 'a':
                    dayGroup.a += Number(list[i].amount)
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    dayGroup.b += Number(list[i].amount)
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            } 
        } 
        
    }
    console.log(daysGroup) 
    return daysGroup
}
```

and here is the result I get:

```
[
    {
    date: '2018-11-30',
    a: 0,
    b: 3
    },
    {
    date: '2018-11-30',
    a: 0,
    b: 3
    },
    {
    date: '2018-11-30',
    a: 0,
    b: 3
    }
]
```

doing my search in the stack I realized some people have solved this issue by putting the new dummy object inside the for loop. But this this messes the result I'm looking for.

my goal is to get a result like this:

```
[
    {
    date: '2018-11-29',
    a: 0,
    b: 2
    },
    {
    date: '2018-11-30',
    a: 0,
    b: 3
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this in a more concise manner with [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const list = [{ amount: 0, date: '2018-11-29', source: 'a' }, { amount: 2, date: '2018-11-29', source: 'b' }, { amount: 3, date: '2018-11-30', source: 'b' } ] 

const result = list.reduce((r, {date, amount, source}) => {
  r[date] = r[date] || {date, a: 0, b: 0}
  r[date][source] += amount
  return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

The idea is to `group` by `date` and while doing that keep summing the `source` amounts.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know about reduce. Though my problem has been solved, I have to spend more time studying you solution to understand it. Best.